# Build legacy project built with Flash SDK 2

Tags: flash, adobe, flash-builder

First of all, I am not a Flash developer. Recently I got a bunch of applications from my client, most of them are written in PHP and Node.js with frontend technologies HTML5, CSS3, and AngularJS. One of the legacy application is using Flash as the frontend technology. It is mentioned by them that for any frontend changes in Flash application, I need Flash SDK 2 for taking new builds.

I started searching on the internet for downloading Flash SDK 2 and I couldn't find it anywhere. I want to know the below points

1. Can I give support for this particular application?
2. Is Flash SDK 2 available?
3. Why is the SDK not available?

   It requires only some text changes and not much functionality changes. Please adivse me how to proceed further. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as Flash SDK 2. Most likely they meant [**Flex**](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex.html) SDK 2 since it was popular for GUI design (If GUI is what you meant by *"...using Flash as the front-end technology"*)

> **1.** Can I give support for this particular application?

Define "give support". Flex code uses [MXML](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&q=flex+mxml) and the ActionScript 3.0 programming language. Since you're only changing texts, it should be easy to find Strings and text labels within the code.

The updated code must be compiled into a newer SWF file (a `.swf` is the output of your AS3/Flex code. The file is run on browser via Flash plugin).

Either use command-line tools (included with SDK) to edit/compile or use Adobe [Animate CC](https://www.adobe.com/uk/products/animate.html). Animate CC is advertised as an animation software but it has a code IDE part to it.

> **2.** Is Flash SDK 2 available? **3.** Why is the SDK not available?

That version number is old and the current version is **4.6**. See downloads here:

https://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/flex-sdk-download.html

Comment: this project was created more than 10 years back. I cannot rebuild the same using the latest SDK.

Comment: _"I cannot rebuild the same..."_ what was the first error that made you think you need the older version SDK? Usually everything latest is backwards compatible apart from rare cases of deprecated commands. Without changing anything, just test by re-compiling your 10 yr old source code with latest SDK. What error causes can't _"cannot rebuild"_?